# Product customizing quiz - quiz adding products to the cart

Tags: plugins, functions, customization, woocommerce-offtopic

Spend a lot of time on this and my client is getting angry but still no results…

Is there any plugin (or solution to use) you know to instantly add product to cart after giving specific answer on a quiz? Cannot find anything like that. I’ve tried Product Recommendation Quiz but It just counts “votes” after every answer and then allows customer to manually add specific product to the cart. I would like to make it happen automatically. For eg “How old are you?” And when i click answer “more than 60 years old” it drops a vitamin pack (or better - 1000mg Vitamin C) into my basket immediately. Examples are: HUM Nutrition | Vitamins for Skin, Body & Mood, and https://www.gainful.com/quiz/ Thanks for your help, i would really appreciate it…

Comment: Hi - we don't really do plugin recommendations here sorry, or WooCommerce. Hopefully there's a more WooCommerce-specific place you can get better recommendations

Comment: I think a lot of WordPress forms plugins support questionnaire / wizards though so you might have some luck using one of those, and hopefully can hook the form submission into a product add.